# How to force swagger to use only some Generic Parameters while generating doc

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I have clas with two generic parameters:

```c#
[DataContract]
public class EntityReference<T, TId> where T : EntityBase<TId>
{
    [DataMember(Name = "Id")]
    public TId RefId { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public T Object { get; set; }
}
```

What swagger does is it generates new Definition for every Generic Parameter combination it encounters, but since Object Property is ignored, we only need to have definition for different types of TId.

Is there a way to force swagger to generate definitions only for some of the Generic Params?

I've tried SchemaFilter but the entries in SchemaRegistry are created before the Apply method is run and Refs are set after it runs.

EDIT1:
I'm using Swashbuckle

Comment: Do you use Swashbuckle or Swagger-Net?

Comment: @Helen I'm using Swashbuckle. I Also edited the question to Reflect this.